# How to add new command to a buffer by buffer number

Tags: buffers

`-buffer` flag in `:command` adds a command to the current buffer but how can I add command to a buffer by a given buffer number.

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way to define a command to a single buffer that's not the current buffer... If you want to accomplish that, I think you need to switch to the buffer you want the command to apply to, create the command, and switch back or otherwise undo the action (e.g. close a split if you opened one for the buffer.)

Comment: if the buffer is displayed in a different window, you could use `win_execute()`